# Proving that a collection of functions is a monotone class

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

My question comes from the proof of Proposition 4.6 in *Probability and Stochastics* by Cinlar. Here is the (slightly paraphrased) statement:

> **Proposition 4.6**: *Let $T$ be arbitrary. For each $t$ in $T$, let $X_t$ be a random variable taking values in some measurable space $(E_t,\mathcal{E}_t)$. Then $V: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\sigma \{X_t: t \in T\}$-measurable if and only if there exists a sequence $(t_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $T$ and a $\left(\otimes_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{t_n}\right)$-measurable function $f$ such that*
> $$ V = f(X_{t_1},X_{t_2},\ldots). $$

The proof of sufficiency is easy. For proving necessity, the author applies the Monotone Class Theorem for functions. My question is on proving that the relevant class of functions is indeed a monotone class. I have checked the first two conditions for a monotone class, but I am stuck on showing the third. For completeness, here is the book's definition of a monotone class:

> **Definition.** *Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a collection of numerical functions on $E$. Let $\mathcal{M}_{+}$ be the subcollection consisting of nonnegative functions in $\mathcal{M}$, and let $\mathcal{M}_b$ be the subcollection of bounded functions in $\mathcal{M}$. Then $\mathcal{M}$ is a* ***monotone class** if*:  
> (a) $1 = 1_E \in \mathcal{M}$   
> (b) $f,g \in \mathcal{M}_b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R} \implies af + bg \in \mathcal{M}$ 
> (c) $(f_n) \subset \mathcal{M}_{+}$ and $f_n \nearrow f \implies f \in \mathcal{M}$.

For this proof, $\mathcal{M}$ is the following:
$$ \mathcal{M} := \left\{V: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R} }\,|\, \exists (t_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset T \text{ and a } \left(\otimes\mathcal{E}_{t_n}\right)\text{-measurable } f \text{ so that }   V = f(X_{t_1},X_{t_2},\ldots) \right\} $$

Here is what I have so far:

(a) It's clear that $1 = 1_{\Omega} \in \mathcal{M}$ because $1_{\Omega} = 1_{\times_n E_{t_n}} \circ (X_{t_1},X_{t_2},\ldots)$ for any sequence $(t_n)$ in $T$ and any $\left(\otimes_{n} \mathcal{E}_n  \right)$-measurable function $f$.

(b) Suppose that $U,V \in \mathcal{M}_b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then there exist sequences $(t_n)$ and $(s_n)$ in $T$, and functions $f$ and $g$ that are $(\otimes_{n} \mathcal{E}_{t_n})$-measurable and $(\otimes_n \mathcal{E}_{s_n})$-measurable, respectively, such that $U = f(X_{t_1},X_{t_2},\ldots)$ and $V = g(X_{s_1}, X_{s_2},\ldots).$
Now let $(r_k)_{k=1}^{\infty} := (t_1,s_1,t_2,s_2,\ldots)$ and define $h: \times_{k=1}^{\infty} E_{r_k} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by

$$ h(x_{t_1},x_{s_1},x_{t_2},x_{s_2},\ldots) := a f(x_{t_1},x_{t_2},\ldots) + b g(x_{s_1},x_{s_2},\ldots)   $$

so that $aU + bV = h(X_{t_1},X_{s_1},X_{t_2},X_{s_2},\ldots)$. Then to show that $aU + bV$ is in $\mathcal{M}$, it suffices to show that $h$ is $\left(\otimes_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{r_k}\right)$-measurable. And to show this, it suffices to show that the maps
\begin{align*}
    \tilde{f}: (x_{t_1},x_{s_1},x_{t_2},x_{s_2},\ldots) \mapsto f(x_{t_1},x_{t_2},\ldots) 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    \tilde{g}: (x_{t_1},x_{s_1},x_{t_2},x_{s_2},\ldots) \mapsto g(x_{s_1},x_{s_2},\ldots) 
\end{align*}
are both $\left(\otimes_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{r_k}\right)$-measurable, since $h = a \tilde{f} + b \tilde{g}$ and $\left(\otimes_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{r_k}\right)$-measurable functions are closed under linear combinations. We see that $\tilde{f} = f \circ \pi_T$, where $\pi_T: \times_{k=1}^{n} E_{r_k} \to \times_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{t_n}$ is the map

$$ \pi_T: (x_{t_1},x_{s_1},x_{t_2},x_{s_2},\ldots) \mapsto (x_{t_1},x_{t_2},\ldots). $$

Clearly, if $R$ is a measurable rectangle in $\times_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{t_n}$ then $\pi_T^{-1}(R)$ is a measurable rectangle in $\times_{k=1}^{\infty} E_{r_k}$. Hence, $\pi$ is measurable with respect to $\otimes_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{r_k}$ and $\otimes_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{t_n}$, and therefore $\tilde{f}$ is $\left(\otimes_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{r_k}\right)$-measurable. And by an analogous argument, $\tilde{g}$ is also $\left(\otimes_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{r_k}\right)$-measurable. Hence, $a \tilde{f} + b \tilde{g} = h$ is $\left(\otimes_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{r_k}\right)$-measurable, and so $aU + bV \in \mathcal{M}$.

**I'm stuck at (c). Here's my current attempt:**

(c) Suppose that $(V_k) \subset \mathcal{M}_{+}$ and $V_k \nearrow V$. We want to show that $V \in \mathcal{M}$. Since each $V_k$ is in $\mathcal{M}$, there exists a sequence $(t_n^{(k)}) = (t_1^{(k)},t_2^{(k)},\ldots)$ (depending on $k$, hence the superscripts) and an $(\otimes_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{t_n^{(k)}})$-measurable function $f_k$ such that
$$V_k = f_k(X_{t_1^{(k)}}, X_{t_2^{(k)}}, \ldots).$$
To show that $V \in \mathcal{M}$, we need to show that $V = f(X_{j_1},X_{j_2},\ldots)$ for some sequence $(j_m) \subset T$ and some $\left( \otimes_{m = 1}^{\infty} \mathcal{E}_{j_{m}}\right)$-measurable function $f$. And here I got stuck...

**How do I complete the proof of (c)?**

My initial thinking was to somehow mimic the proof of the previous theorem that treats the case of a single random variable $X$. That theorem states: For a given random variable $X$ taking values in $(E,\mathcal{E})$, a map $V: \Omega \to \mathbb{\overline{R}}$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable if and only if $V = f \circ X$ for some $\mathcal{E}$-measurable function $f$. The proof of this theorem used the Monotone Class Theorem  with
$$\mathcal{M} := \{V: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}\,|\,V = f \circ X \text{ for some } \mathcal{E}\text{-measurable function } f \}.$$

To show that $\mathcal{M}_{+}$ is closed under increasing limits, the author argues as follows: If $(V_n) \subset \mathcal{M}_{+}$ and $V_n \nearrow V$, then for each $n$ there is an $\mathcal{E}$-measurable function $f_n$ such that $V_n = f_n \circ X$. Then $f: = \sup_n f_n$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable and
$$ V(\omega) = \sup_n V_n(\omega) = \sup_n f_n(X(\omega)) = f(X(\omega)), \quad \omega \in \Omega. $$

But I can't see how to carry this argument over to the more general theorem. In particular, I'm not sure how to choose a sequence $(j_m)$, and how to choose a corresponding $f$ that satisfies the required conditions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The key is to recognise that the coordinate set $\{t_n^{(k)}:n,k\in \mathbb N\}$ is countable, so is equal to the set $\{s_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, for some sequence $s_n$. We can thus re-express the functions $f_k$ in terms of $s_n$:

$$
V_k = \tilde f_k(X_{s_1}, X_{s_2}, \dots),
$$

at which point the proof follows exactly as in the single-variable case.

Comment: Thanks very much for your post! Let me see if I have this right. Is $\tilde{f}_k := f_k \circ \alpha_k$, where $\alpha_k$ is the projection/permutation map $\alpha_k: (X_{s_1}(\omega), X_{s_2}(\omega),\ldots) \mapsto (X_{t_1^{(k)}}(\omega) , X_{t_2^{(k)}}(\omega), \ldots)$ ?

Comment: @Leonidas Yes, exactly. Projection maps are trivially measurable, so the $\tilde f_k$ are measurable, and they're all functions of the same sequence, so that's your $j_m$.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Also, on second thought, since as you say the set $\{t_n^{(k)}: n,k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is actually *equal* to the set  $\{s_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, then the map I wrote in my previous comment would actually just be a permutation, not a projection, right?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Leonidas Sorry, ignore that comment - it's a projection, not a permutation, since in general $\alpha_k$ ignores all the coordinates $t_n^{(l)}$ for $l \ne k$.